# Prove that $H = \langle a, b \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group.
>   Prove that for all $a,b \in G$, the set $$H = \langle a,b\rangle =\{a^m b^n | m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I tried to check that the following $3$ criteria hold, but I couldn't proceed using the definition of $H$.

\begin{align}
 & e \in H \\ 
 & ab \in H \\
 & a^{-1} \in H \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I prove the more general case for which your question is a special case.

> Suppose $S\subset G$ is some subset of a group $G$. Then $\langle S\rangle$, the subgroup generated  by $S$, is indeed a group.

By definition $\langle S\rangle:=\left\{\prod_{i=1}^ls_i:l\in\mathbb{N_0},\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,l\}\ ( s_i\in S \vee s_i^{-1}\in S)\right\}$, with the empty product equal to $e\in G$. Now clearly $\langle S\rangle\neq\varnothing$, since $e\in\langle S\rangle$ (even when $S=\varnothing$). Now suppose $a,b\in\langle S\rangle$. Thus for certain $l_1,l_2\in\mathbb{N_0}$, and $s_1,\ldots,s_{l_1},s'_1,\ldots,s'_{l_2}\in S$, $a=\prod_{i=1}^{l_1}s_i$ and $b=\prod_{i=1}^{l_2}s'_i$, thus $ab^{-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{l_1}s_i\left(\prod_{j=1}^{l_2}s'_j\right)^{-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{l_1}s_i\prod_{j=1}^{l_2}(s'_{l_2-j+1})^{-1}$. By looking once again at the definition of $\langle S\rangle$ we see $ab^{-1}\in\langle S\rangle$, as desired. Thus $\langle S\rangle\subset G$ is indeed a subgroup.

Comment: hi , yes i could also prove that  ab^-1∈⟨S⟩, but still i didn't understand how you proved that part

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: how i show that ab^-1∈H ?

Comment: $ab^{-1}$ is a finite product of (inverses of) elements in $S$, as you can see in my proof. By definition of $\langle S\rangle$, this is contained in $\langle S\rangle$. (see the definition I gave)